# What is causing context cancelled while calling kafka client function Produce?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, goroutine, franz-go

My Producer application pushes a record to a topic in Kafka. I keep getting error context cancelled on trying to Produce the record. I tried to check the Brokers using Ping function but no error is returned.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()
kafkaClient.Produce(ctx, record, func(record *kgo.Record, err error) {
        if err != nil {
            errorCallbackFn(err)
            return
        }
        successCallbackFn()
    })
```

Using the package:
github.com/twmb/franz-go/pkg/kgo

Tried to check if broker urls are wrong but ping is working fine so concluded kafka url is ok.
Also tried increasing the timeout. That didnt help either.
Error:
context canceled

> kgo.(*Client).finishRecordPromise (producer.go:484)
> github.com/twmb/franz-go/pkg/kgo kgo.(*producer).finishPromises
> (producer.go:458) github.com/twmb/franz-go/pkg/kgo
> kgo.(*producer).promiseBatch.func1 (producer.go:438)
> github.com/twmb/franz-go/pkg/kgo runtime.goexit (asm_arm64.s:1172)
> runtime
>
> - Async Stack Trace kgo.(*producer).promiseBatch (producer.go:438) github.com/twmb/franz-go/pkg/kgo

Comment: You must show the context you actually use, what timeout/deadline is set etc.

Comment: Ping doesn't check ports. Also, producers buffer requests, and don't send immediately. So, do you need a Context with a timeout?